# How to check file extensions in R

Tags: r

```
dset<-data.frame(x1=c(1,2),x2=c(3,4))

aaa<-function(data,fnm){
# if fnm have .txt extensions
if  {
write.table(data,fnm)
}
#   if fnm have .txt extensions,add .txt
else {
write.table(data,fnm)
}

}

aaa(data=dset,fnm=d:\\aaa)
aaa(data=dset,fnm=d:\\aaa.txt)
```

How to check file extensions in R? If the file has .txt extension then write, else add .txt then write.Thanks!

Comment: Look at `tools::file_ext`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to check just for txt extension is:

```
grepl("\\.txt$", fnm)
# TRUE if the file name has txt extension
```

So the full code might be something like this:

```
fnm <- if(grepl("\\.txt$", fnm)) fnm else paste0(fnm, ".txt")
# adds ".txt" to `fnm` only if it's not already there
```

Comment: aaa(data=dset,fnm="d:\\aaa") is right. If I want to use aaa(data=dset,fnm=d:\\aaa),How to do it? Thank you!

Comment: Just don't do that. It's a terrible idea.

Comment: I don't get what you mean by `aaa(data=dset,fnm=d:\\aaa)`? Is it that you don't want the file name to be quoted? Then I must agree with Dason. It's a terrible idea, and worse still, generally impossible to achieve.

Comment: Thanks for Dason and lebatsnok.